# Unable to perform jquery validations

Tags: php

I am developing a website in php and I require jquery validations. I am using validator for it. I have loaded the jquery file and `validate.js` file and have it in my local folder, but I am unable to perform validations.

The error message is `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDefaults' of undefined "`.

I am stuck in this step. Please help me.

Jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {


       jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
           debug: true,
           success: "valid"
       });
       $("#Myform").validate({
           rules: {
               inputEmail: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 2

               }

           }

       });
    });
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="Myform" method="get" action="">
<div class="content">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="username">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You will have to post the code which is throwing this error. Also the code which is providing data to the code which produces this error.

Comment: please post your code which results the error.

Comment: Show your code @Ishwarya

Comment: Is there any errors on developer console? I prefer Chrome over Firefox for debugging Javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should be included before jQuery validation plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works in Fiddle. But in my project, I am unable to do. My error always says "cannot call setdefaults undefined". I tried loading my jquery files both locally and from web. Still it fails.

Answer (score 0):

1)use only one jquery.validate.js
2)jquery.validate.min.js is just  minified version of jquery.validate.js

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js">
    </script>
        <script>
    $(function () {$("#submit").click(function ()  //input button click
        {
             $.validator.setDefaults({
                   debug: true,
                   success: "valid" 
               });
               $("#Myform").validate({
                   rules: {
                       inputEmail: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 2

                       }

                   }

               });
            }); 
            }); 
        </script>

    <form id="Myform" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="content">

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="username">
           <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" placeholder="submit"> 
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="Myform" method="get" action="">
        <div class="content">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {


           jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
               debug: true,
               success: "valid"
           });
           $("#Myform").validate({
               rules: {
                   inputEmail: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength: 2

                   }

               }

           });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of just posting a code dump, could you please explain briefly what you have changed in the code and why it solves the problem?

Comment: Yes, You need to call Jquery.js first, and then other jquery files. So validate.js should be called after jquery,js